# UICollectionView cells are not scrolling properly when embedded inside a vertical UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Can you please help me with this problem.

Please see the attached image which has got all the details.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n1Gx.png)

I have a vertical scrollView that has multiple CollectionView areas each with one row of listing cells horizontally. (Just like Facebook app friend suggestions/ advertisements). I have fixed image on top, a text and then comes there collection view areas to implement three horizontal sliders.

The whole page scrolls fine vertically, but after a certain section horizontal scrolls on the cells gets stuck. Collection view cells are moving, when scrolled within the main window before any vertical scrolling of the page. After a a little bit vertical scrolling happens, the collection view area is getting cut into two halves - upper section is scrollable, lower section is stuck. And anything (another collection view with cells) below that is also stuck.

Please refer to the image. I have spent a lot of time to draw this diagram to clearly represent the problem.  I am using storyboard auto layouts.

Please help me out with some suggestions.

Thanks a lot..
Arinjoy

Comment: It sounds like your scroll view doesn't extend all the way to the bottom of the screen, but isn't clipping subviews. Pause in the debugger and run `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at the `(lldb)` prompt. Copy the output and paste it into your question as code.

Comment: Hi, I figured out the solution. Thanks for your tips though. I will use that in future.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks..I figured out the solution. The content view height was not being set properly and getting clipped off by the screen size.

I had to manually calculate the size and set them in the code like below:

```
    // calculating and setting the height constarint on the content view.
    // It depends on the screen resolution and the fixed area size of the page (i.e. exclucding welcome image which is 35% of the screen height)

    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    let contentHeight = self.contentView.frame.size.height

    self.contentView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(screenHeight * 0.35 + contentHeight + 300).active = true
```

Comment: Thanks really Appreciated your Help.